# Nested conjunctive query

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, subquery

I created the code below for a query that is supposed to return the records that satisfies two conditions:

1- ID is equal to #7

2- Disease is equal to one of the diseases written between the single quotes

The record with ID = 7 in the database I'm applying this query on doesn't have any of the diseases listed in the query as a value for the attribute "disease", so the query shouldn't return any record as a result. Yet it is returning the tuple with ID = 7 as a result for the query. Can you please tell me what is the problem with my code? I tried replacing the (||) with the word (OR) but I'm still getting the same result.

```
SELECT *
FROM patients
WHERE disease = ( 'migraine' || 'stroke' || 'concussion' || 'down_syndrome' || 'epilepsy' || 'autism' || 'hydrocephalus' || 'dyslexia' || 'dystonia' || 'aphasia' || 'coma' || 'aneurysm' || 'batten_disease' || 'brain_cancer' || 'alzheimers_disease' || 'amyolrophic_alteral_sclerosis' )
AND ID = '7'
```

Comment: What is your database - MySQL or Oracle? Choose one - or are you seeing the same behavior in both? Please use the proper tag(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant to use an `IN` operator like

```
SELECT *
FROM patients
WHERE disease IN ( 'migraine', 'stroke' , 'concussion' , 'down_syndrome' , 'epilepsy' , 'autism' , 'hydrocephalus' , 'dyslexia' ,'dystonia' , 'aphasia' , 'coma' ,'aneurysm' , 'batten_disease' , 'brain_cancer' , 'alzheimers_disease' , 'amyolrophic_alteral_sclerosis' )
AND ID = '7';
```

**Edit:** per comment: `||` is a concatenation operator and not a `OR` condition and so ultimately you getting a string concatanated with all diseases and that you are trying to compare.

Comment: No, read the question... the OP states that this query (as written) should not return any rows, but it does. He/she wants to know why. Your advice is sound, but it does not answer the question asked.

Comment: @mathguy, Thanks for pointing it, missed somehow but anyways OP meant to use `IN` condition and I think he mistaked `||` with `OR` condition. His posted query shouldn't return anything in reality.